# -webkit-transform breaking background animation

Tags: css, google-chrome, background, css-animations, css-transforms

In an attempt to practice my transforms, I created a simple animation that moved three divs using absolute position and transformed each of them as well position to position. This worked just as expected without any flaws

However, whenever webkit browsers transform the divs, the divs no longer retain their ability to animate to the next color, they remain their original color (most of the time black)

[**Here's a jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cL5bW/)

I attempted to fix the solution by giving a default div a background color, by applying a transform that did nothing, and adding `!important` to the new background color but none of the fixes worked. I know the keyframe is being reached because the elements still change transform and location, but the new background color is not applying

It works perfectly fine in the newest version of Firefox for me (when the comment is taken out)

Do I have an error I haven't seen? If not, are there any work arounds for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it's the issue appears when trying to animate both `transform` and the position (via `left` and `top`)

**Try using just `transform`,** here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qA4V9/

**Notice:** percentages in the `translate()` function refer to the object's width and height, rather than its container like `top` and `left`, so you'll have to rethink those numbers (I used pixels)

**Good news:** it will have much better performance (especially on mobile)
http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/

Comment: You are correct, this is a good work around. I always seem to forget about translates in occasions like these. I suppose that's why I need the practice!